# mysql and or query together

Tags: mysql

How can i run mysql and or query together instant of separate query.
e.g.:

And query:

```
select * form tablename where name='A' and password="A" and id='A';
```

Or query:

```
select * form tablename where name='A' or password="A" or id='A';
```

-These are 2 different query,can i make these query together?what is the syntax??

Comment: The queries are the same. *confused*

Answer (score 10):

Use parentheses to group the conditions?

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (X and Y or Z) AND (P and Q or F)`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can just union them but, since one is a subset of the other, it's not strictly necessary:

```
select * from tablename
    where name = 'A' and password = 'A' and id = 'A'
union select * from tablename
    where name = 'A' or password = 'A' or id = 'A'
```

That will give you exactly the same results as if you had just run the second query on its own. That will make sense once you realise that every single row from the first query has a `name` equal to `'A'`, so it will match the first part of the `where` clause in the second query.

If you want duplicate rows for those returned in both queries, just use `union all` instead of `union`.

If you were using `'A'` as just a placeholder and its values are different in the two queries, then you have two approaches. Use a construct like:

```
... where (name = 'A' and password = 'B' and id = 'C')
       or  name = 'D' or  password = 'E' or  id = 'F'
```

or use the `union` solution I gave above, something like:

```
select * from tablename
    where name = 'A' and password = 'B' and id = 'C'
union select * from tablename
    where name = 'D' or password = 'E' or id = 'F'
```

(use `union all` when you *know* there is no possibility of duplicates between the two queries, - it will save the DBMS the trouble of removing non-existent duplicates - that's not the case with these queries).

The `union` *may* give better performance on a DBMS that can hive off the two selects more easily to separate query engines (something that would be more difficult with a single query with a complex where clause). Of course, as will all optimisations, measure, don't guess.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you expect as the result, but my guess is you want a UNION:

```
SELECT 1 `query`, `name`, `password`, `id`
FROM `tablename` WHERE `name`='A' and `password`='A' and `id`='A'
UNION
SELECT 2 `query`, `name`, `password`, `id`
FROM `tablename` WHERE `name`='A' or `password`='A' or `id`='A'
```

Note that the first column `query` in result is required to separate results from the two queries because union of (X and Y) and (X or Y) is always (X or Y).

Answer (score 0):

Use `()` for such type of conditions

```
select * form tablename
         where name='A' OR password="A" OR id='A' OR 
                    (name='A' AND password="A" AND id='A')
```

If you want to check for same string as `A` here then you will get same o/p using following query

```
select * form tablename
         where name='A' OR password="A" OR id='A'
```

Comment: The final part "OR (...)" is superfluous, by the way.

Comment: @paxdiablo :- i update my answer but as he want to know how to use `AND` and `OR` in single query i am not deleting any of the above.

Comment: No, that's probably a good thing. It hadn't originally occurred to me that 'A' may just be a placeholder different in the two conditions, not a literal value guaranteed to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the conditions with `WHERE`

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE (name='A' AND password='A' AND id='A') OR name='A' OR password='A' OR id='A'
```

The parentheses ensure that the whole `AND` expressions "validates" only if ALL the containing conditions are true while the rest macthes the `OR`